# GridView DevExpress check if any cell is null

Tags: c#, devexpress

[image]

I need to check if a cell is empty and store a message to then create a new cell in every row that contains all the messages

But I don't know know how to work with DevExpress can someone help with my code

```
    string Name = "First Name";
    string FName = "Father Name";
    string LName = "Last Name";
    string EmpCode = "Employee Code";
    string Tax = "Tax#";
    string SocSec = "Soc.Sec#";
    string EmpType = "Employment Type";
    string DepCode = "Department Code";
    string DepDesc = "Department Description";
    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\Emp.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes\"";

            con.Open();
            DataTable dtSchema;
            dtSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand ("select * FROM [" + dtSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]", con);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(Command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

This loop isn't giving me the right message about empty cells I think it's not right what i wrote maybe there's another better way...

```
        for (int rows = 0 ; rows < gridView3.RowCount ; rows ++)
        {
            string[] msg = new string[50];

            if ((gridView3.GetRowCellValue(rows, gridView3.Columns["LName"])) == null)
            {
                msg[rows] = "name missing";
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can ask your question here : http://community.devexpress.com/forums/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know the cell's value won't be null.  The underlying datasource however will have a null value.

To check if a cell's data is null or summed from nulls:

```
private bool IsNullValue(PivotDrillDownDataSource ds, PivotGridField field)
{
    if (ds.RowCount == 0 || field == null) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.RowCount; i++)
    {
        if (Equals(ds[i][field], null))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

To change text in null cell:

```
if (IsNullValue(e.CreateDrillDownDataSource(), e.DataField))
     e.DisplayText = "NULL OR SUM WITH NULL";
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and below code worked fine for me, just slightly changed from this what OP tried. I hope it will help somebody.

```
for (int rows = 0 ; rows < gridView3.RowCount ; rows ++)
    {
        string[] msg = new string[50];

        if ((gridView3.GetRowCellValue(rows, "LName")) == null)
        {
            msg[rows] = "name missing";
        }
    }
```

LName need to replaced by string fieldName.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void gridViewPro_RowStyle(object sender, 
    DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e)
{
    GridView View = sender as GridView;
    if (e.RowHandle >= 0)
    {
        double Sale = Convert.ToDouble(
            View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["PRO_S3M"]));
        double Qua = Convert.ToDouble(
            View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["PRO_QTY"]));
        if (Sale > 0 && Qua > 0)
        {
            if (Sale >= Qua)
            {
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use This Event Of AspxGridView

```
 protected void grid_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e)
{        // Get Cell Values here and compare as per your conditions
    string text = e.CellValue.ToString();                   
 }
```

Comment: Then Please Look at the following Link, There are multiple examples given on how to retrieve the cell values of grid and set it accordingly   http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument753